# dual boot arch/windows10 on separate disks systemd UEFI

Tags: linux, boot, bios, arch-linux, systemd

I'm obviously missing something in how BIOS determines which disk to boot with UEFI.  I have a dual boot setup with two SSD disks. Disk0 has Arch, Disk1 has Windows10. Ordinarily I use systemd boot on Disk0 to boot Arch or Windows.

I needed to upgrade Windows10 and it fails in dual boot, so I disconnected Disk0. The system didn't have any trouble booting into Windows, so I finished the upgrade and restarted a couple of times just to make sure the upgrade had completed.

I then put Disk0 back in but Windows10 loads directly and I don't have a UEFI boot option in BIOS for Arch on Disk0 any longer.

Removing Disk1 still doesn't allow booting from Disk0.

How does BIOS detect a valid UEFI partition and why wouldn't it now detect the partition on Disk0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered that BIOS doesn't detect EFI partitions on disk but instead are told about them. UEFI stores boot manager information in NVRAM.  In my case Windows overwrote the systemd-boot NVRAM entry with one of its own even though it already had one.
I used the arch installation media and ran 'efibootmgr' to delete the duplicate Windows10 entry and add an entry for systemd-boot/arch as per this wiki https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#efibootmgr